# Is it possible to change the Max Record Count on an portal ArcGIS hosted Feature service?

Tags: arcgis-server

We can modify the MaxRecordCount of published feature layer on arcgis server using the code mentioned on the following url:

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/example-edit-service-properties.htm
Can we use the same code to modify feature count of feature layer published on portal ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can. Try inserting "admin/" path in your hosted layer url between "/rest/" and "/services/", eg:

```
http://services1.arcgis.com/example/arcgis/rest/admin/services/MyFeature/FeatureServer/0?token=0xtokenhex0x
```

Here you should have access to the "Update Definition" link at the bottom which would allow you to change the "maxRecordCount" value. Hope this helps.